# No logs in production dockerized rails-application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, dokku

I use dokku to dockerize and deploy my rails-application. Ruby 2.5.1, Rails 5.2.1

It works fine, but i can't see logs of server.

`dokku logs <app> -p web` and `docker logs <container_id>` return nothing.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ruby:2.5.1
RUN echo 'deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ stretch-pgdg main' >  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list
RUN wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | apt-key add -
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs postgresql-client-10
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash - && apt-get install -y nodejs less
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY Gemfile /app/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /app/Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install
COPY . /app
```

Tried this two settings in **production.rb** but nothing helped

```
  #1
  if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
    logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger    = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
  end

  #2
  config.logger = Logger.new('/proc/1/fd/1')
```

**Procfile**

```
web: bundle exec rails s -p 5000
```

Comment: Do you mean you tried to set the `RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT` env variable?

Comment: Yep, not working

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered exactly the same issue but in *development*.

In my case, the reason was outdated [puma server itself](https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/1906).

> 4.0.1->4.1.0, Rails logs flushing incorrectly

I could see the logs after upgrading the puma gem.